# TechnicalProfile called several times with changing objectId

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure B2C and have created a Custom Policy that should call and azure function to create a user in the customer database.  The Azure function works and is being called.

**PROBLEM**
I sign up for a new account and the flow runs, however the REST-CreateUser is being called twice each time with a different objectId.  I then look at the AD users only to see that the objectId for the user is completely different too.

1. The technical Profile to call and Azure Function

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-CreateUser">
          <DisplayName>Create a user in the database</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary"
            Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://[REDACTED]/api/v1/user</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ApiKeyHeader</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="x-functions-key" StorageReferenceId="[REDACTED]" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

1. Orchestration Step in SignUpOrSignIn User Journey

```
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <!-- Skip this orchestration step if newUser doesn't exist. -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
            <!-- Skip this orchestration step if newUser doesn't equal to true. -->
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>newUser</Value>
              <Value>true</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="RESTGreateUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-CreateUser" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

Tried changing it to `sub`, but I read several articles indicating I should move away from sub and use `objectId`

Answer (score 0):

After a novice blindly 'hacking' away with many different things, it started working after I added this to one of the TechnicalProfile's.

```
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

If anyone would like to attempt to explain why this fixed it or even if this is the right fix, please feel free to elaborate.

My Journey is calling all the right things, I am getting the claims I want so I am a happy camper.